# Hide Keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, resignfirstresponder

I want to hide the keyboard after entering the data.

I have tried both methods which are given below.

```
[self.textField resignFirstResponser];
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Both are working well but i want to know the difference between these two lines.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, both the methods are used to hide the keyboard or lose the focus on a TextField. The `[self.view EndEditing:YES]` tells the program to end any editing process that are taking place in a view (or its subview). Hence, it apparently hides the keyboard that was up for editing. This happens regardless of any specific textfield. Whereas, `[self.textField resignFirstResponder]` method resigns its response towards editing the specified textField in the method (self.textField). Thus loses focus and hides the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.view endEdtiting:YES];
```

From Docs:

"Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status."

"force: Specify YES to force the first responder to resign, regardless of whether it wants to do so.
ReturnValue: YES if the view resigned the first responder status or NO if it did not."

```
[self.textField resignFirstReponder];
```

"Notifies the receiver that it has been asked to relinquish its status as first responder in its window"

Answer (score 0):

Sending the `-endEditing:(BOOL)`force call to the view containing the input first responder will cause the text field to be sent a resign message, causing the on-screen keyboard to be dismissed. 
`resignFirstResponder` removes the present first responder in the `UIResponder` hierarchy